# Create SQL sentece according to users input MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

what I want  to do is this:

First  have a form that has 5 input for example:

```
Name: 
Career: 
Experience:
City:
Speciality:
```

what I need to do is create a **sql** sentence according to the fields that are filled. If only 2 field were filled create a sql with only those fields. I don't have any idea how to do this besides creating a sql sentence for every possibility which turns out to be a pretty extensive work. i read that i could use store procedures, but again I don't know how I would do it. please help me!

---

well sorry if i didn't elaborate the question.

here is the deal i have diferent tables in mysql database

- person

  - person_id
  - name
  - last_name
- person_courses

  - person_id
  - course
- person_carrer

  - person_id
  - carrer
- person_experience

  - person_id
  - position
  - experience_description
  - experience_from_date
  - experience_to_date

all this tables are related to person by foreign_key (person_id)

then i have a page where user have 6 diferent inputs:

- name:
- last_name:
- courses:
- experience:(this fields search position and experience_description from table person_experience)
- antiquity:(must obtain a sumatory of all person_experience)

the user must obtain results according to the fields he filled.

what i tried to do is create a complex SQL sentence using "%%" like this

```
select a.person_id, b.name, c.last_name, d.courses, f.experience, g.antiquity
from person a,
    (
     'SQL SENTENCE' WHERE NAME LIKE "%%"
    ) b,
    (
     'SQL SENTENCE' WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE "%%"
    ) c,
    (
     'SQL SENTENCE' WHERE COURSE LIKE "%%" GROUP BY PERSON_ID
    ) d, 
    (
     'SQL SENTENCE' WHERE POSITION LIKE "%%" OR EXPERIENCE_DESCRIPTION LIKE "%%" 
      GROUP BY PERSON_ID
    ) f,
    ( 
     'SQL SENTECE' 
     WHERE 'SUMATORY OF ALL PERSON EXPERIENCE, (TO_DATE - FROM_DATE)/365 '>=0 (THIS ZERO WOULD CHANGE IF USER FILLS INPUT ANTIQUITY)
     GROUP BY PERSON_ID
    ) g
    WHERE a.person_id = b.person_id and c.person_id = b.person_id and d.person_id = c.person_id and f.person_id = d.person_id and g.person_id = f.person_id
```

and if the user fills any field i just put the value between '%value%' so this way i get the result, and i get results with this sql sentence but the problem is that  if a person doesn't have a experience or carrer it is not shown  in the result, so i need someway, as i said in the firstplace, just search in the database according to the users filled inputs.

for example  in if the user fills:

- carrer, experience: search all person with that carrer and that experience.
- name: search all person even if they dont have carrer or course or experience with that name

PS: trying to create an sql sentece for every posibility would result in 64 sql senteces and i am not thinking about doing it!

THANK FOR ALL THE HELP IN ADVANCE

Comment: What are you having problems with?  The form? The PHP? The DB table design?  You haven't shown enough tangible process here for us to be able to give you specific help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that may help:

```
$sql = array(); // initialize empty array for data

foreach(array("name", "career", "experience", "city", "speciality") as $key) { // iterate all the form controls
    if(!empty($value = trim($_POST[$key]))) {
        // the form input is filled, so we add it to data array (with proper escaping)
        $sql["`".$key."`"] = "'".mysqli_real_escape_string($value)."'";
    }
}

if(count($sql)) { // only if user had provided some data
    // generate the final SQL statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` ("
        .implode(", ", array_keys($sql)).") VALUES (" // for example (`name`, `career`)
        .implode(", ", array_values($sql)) . ")"; // for example ('Foo', 'Bar')
} else {
    // no informations provided
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! A paragraph of ordinary text is fine, but comments are even better.